# How to specify all columns as "Text" in Text to Columns function in Data tab?

Tags: excel

I have data in a column that needs to be split into multiple columns using Text to Columns in the Data tab. However, there will be a variable amount of columns created for each row, variable from 1 - 1000. In the Text to Columns wizard Step 3, it defaults to 'General' format for all columns. My data involves very big numbers, and I do not want them trailed (rounded), so I need to set the format as Text.

This is a problem to do manually because I would have to go through every column and click Text, and the wizard doesn't even show all the columns unless you scroll. Ideas?

Comment: How to do the above process in VBA?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although it is not exactly what you want (and I see you don't like the idea of scrolling), when you are presented the data preview showing each column as General.

You can select the first column header and holding the Shift key scroll to the right and select ALL of the columns at once.

Then select Text as the data format.
Not the best, but better than selecting each individually.

[image]

Comment: @pnuts You mean the multiple selection in the text to column wizard? It works fine on my Excel 2007...

Answer (score 2):

Click the first column as you would do normally to change its format to text, but then scroll to the last column. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the last column.

This should select all the columns. Now, change the format and finish :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a related problem and I have discovered a work around solution.

I have a .TXT from MYOB (accounting package).   It has some document header information in the first six rows then the table header and the data.  On the Import Wizard it is only showing me two columns (which matches the document header information in the equivalent of A1 and B1) so I can't set the third column to "TEXT" instead of "GENERAL".  It is treating the MYOB account codes as dates which is causing no end of headaches.

I've done the same plenty of times with these MYOB .TXT files before and Excel has picked up the table header row without problems but for some reason it is now having trouble on this file.  Even more strangly it has successfully done it on one of the .TXT files I am trying to use.  I can't see what I am doing differently.

WORKAROUND SOLUTION  (BTW: "Using Excel 2010")
I want the header information but I first set up the import stating at row 7, set the import type for each column and run.  Then I go back to 'Data' -> 'Connections' -> 'Properties' -> 'Definition' Tab -> 'Edit Query' then reset to start at row 1 and click finish and it worked.  Beats me why.